# paper trail editing previous object

Tags: paper-trail-gem

I've been using paper_trail 3.0 for a long time and been happily editing previous versions with the following code;

```
  # Update a level version with a new date or costing
  def update_version(version_id, data)
    version = PaperTrail::Version.find(version_id) # Find the version
    hash = YAML.load(version.object)               # Convert object to a hash
    hash["from_date"] = data[:from_date] unless data[:from_date].nil?    # Update date
    hash["cost_cents"] = data[:cost_cents] unless data[:cost_cents].nil? # Update cost
    version.object = YAML.dump(hash)               # Convert hash back into YAML
    version.save                                   # Save the version
  end
```

After upgrading to paper trail 4.0 this has stopped working as I can no longer do a version.object call. Is there a way to keep editing previous versions easily with version 4.0 of a paper trail and future versions of paper trail?

**Update**

After looking into it further I think the update_version may work but how it's creating the versions is different in paper_trail 4.0

This is how I create the version

```
  has_paper_trail :only => [:from_date],
    :if => Proc.new { |level|
      level.versions.count == 0 || level.versions.item.first != nil && (level.versions.first.item.from_date.nil? || level.from_date > level.versions.first.item.from_date)
    }
```

After putting a byebug in here I found that level.versions.item is nil!

**Update**

Within my tests which are working in paper_trail 3.x but not in 4.x, I use update_attributes. I've noticed that between the two versions paper_trail treats the update_attributes differently. The ': if' rule above is run before update_attributes in 3.x, but in 4.x it runs after. Which means my check on the 'from_date' doesn't work. Therefore it's not creating another version.

**Answer**

I have to move my Proc into the only section like so;

```
has_paper_trail :only => [:from_date => Proc.new { |level|
                              level.versions.count == 0 || level.versions.first.item != nil && (level.versions.first.item.from_date.nil? || level.from_date > level.versions.first.item.from_date)
                            }
                           ]
```

Comment: You posted the answer and posted a bounty also?

Comment: I posted a bounty, then I found the answer and you cannot remove a bounty or answer your own question when you have a bounty. But it's still worth updating and posting the answer incase other people have this problem between upgrades